# How to keep the grid with 3 columns per row in mobile - Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I want to break row in 3 columns in mobile, desktop, etc.
but currently, in mobile, it only shows 1 column per row.

```
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            demotext1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            demotext1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            demotext1
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
             demotext1
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
             demotext1
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
             demotext1
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In bootstraph 4 col-xs-4 is replaced with col-4